# Text not breaking within button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

So I have the following code :

```
<div class="col-md-2">
 <div class="panel">
  <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <div style=" SEE QUESTION ">
     Here is some very long text on purpose here is some very long text on purpose here is some very long text on purpose 
    </div>
   </button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And as you'll see on [this bootply](http://www.bootply.com/z1dMWEXFNy), the display is not as I expect it, no matter what I put in the `style` attribute of the last `<div>`. I've tried many things such as `width:100%`, `word-break: break-all`, `word-wrap: break-word`, etc.

I think I have found it has something to do with the `btn` class on the `<button>` tag (when I remove it, the text inside the button behaves as I expect, but I can't find which CSS propertyont `btn` is forcing the behavior...

Obviously, I expect the text to break when it reaches the maximum width allowed within the button (I put an exemple in the bootply of what the display should look like (more or less))

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that `.btn` has `white-space: nowrap;` (By default of bootstrap)

So you just need to overwrite that with a rule that has `white-space: normal;`.

Answer (score 5):

add `white-space: normal;`

```
   .btn {
        white-space: normal;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use `white-space` attribute

```
    <div style="text-align:left; width:100%; white-space: normal;">
       <p>Here is some very long text on purpose here is some very long text on purpose here is some very long text on purpose </p>
    </div>
```